# change stroke weight image_annotate in r package "magick"

Tags: r, imagemagick

I would like to be able to control the weight of the `stroke` with `image_annotate`. You can see below that although the letters are more or less the same size. One of them was generated when Frink was sized at 2000 with a much smaller stroke to letter width while the second was generated when Frink was sized 330 and has consequentially a much more pronounced stroke.

Is there a mechanism for control stroke weight in image_annotate?

```
library(magick)
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")

frink %>% image_background("hotpink") %>%
  image_scale("1000") %>% image_annotate("CONFIDENTIAL", size = 150, 
               degrees = 60, location = "+250+500", strokecolor = "white") %>% image_scale("330") %>%
 image_annotate("CONFIDENTIAL", size = 50, 
                     degrees = 60, location = "+50+200", strokecolor = "white")
```

[image: Frink]

Comment: In command line ImageMagick, you can use -stroke X to set the thickness of the text or lines.

Comment: Minor correction to the above comment. To set the stroke thickness with command line IM, use "-strokewidth X". To set the color of the line use "-stroke X".

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I am not sure if gets me any closer in R.